# Unable to read cookie in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code in my asp.net web form page_load

```
 if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["timezoneoffset"] != null)
 {
     HttpContext.Current.Session["timezoneoffset"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["timezoneoffset"].Value;
 }
 else
 {
     HttpContext.Current.Session["timezoneoffset"] = 0;
 }
```

When I debug control is flowing through if block. But when I deploy it is going to else. Can somebody help me to read this cookie and set it into a session?

Comment: I feel like we need more context (or rather just more code) like what is initially setting `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["timezoneoffset"]`

Comment: I agree with KSib.  Just because the cookie is there when you run in debug, does not mean that the same cookie is available to the deployment environment.  Since you are on a different site, the cookie for your development test site is probably not available.  Is that what is catching you?  Have you actually set the cookie in production or are you just assuming it should be there since you saw it in testing?

Comment: Where did you set the cookie, and where did you retrieve that cookie back?